# How to store a variable in gnuplot and use it in xrange and in set arrow

Tags: gnuplot

I am new to gnuplot and do not know how to store a variable at the start of gnufile and then use it in rest partof the gnuscript.

The maximum of x-range is equal to the last row in forth column of a file and it varies in every new excersize.
On terminal I can print the maximum xrange by tail -n 1 data.dat | awk '{print $4}' which is giving a number say it is 3.83352.

I tried with the code

```
MAX_XTICK="`tail -n 1 data.dat | awk '{print $4}'`"
```

and then tried to use it in xrange as

```
set xrange [ 0 : "$MAX_XTICK"]
```

but it is giving me error below error
plot.gnu", line 64: Can't plot with an empty x range!

I am expecting to use MAX_XTICK variable in xrange as

```
xrange [ 0 : MAX_XTICK].
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for external scripts. Check `help stats` and `help show variables`.

```
stats "data.dat" u 4

set xrange [0:STATS_max]
```

In the above example, after performing the `stats` command, the gnuplot variable `STATS_max` contains the maximumm of the 4th column.