# How to hide output from a stats commands in gnuplot

Tags: statistics, gnuplot

This is from my original problem which has closed here

[how-to-store-a-variable-in-gnuplot-and-use-it-in-xrange-and-in-set-arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57890274/how-to-store-a-variable-in-gnuplot-and-use-it-in-xrange-and-in-set-arrow)

The stats commands worked for me as

```
stats case.".data.agr" u 4
```

but it is showing the output of stats on terminal like this

```
* FILE: 
  Records:           33656
  Out of range:          0
  Invalid:               0
  Column headers:        0
  Blank:                 0
  Data Blocks:           1

* COLUMN: 
  Mean:               1.9161
  Std Dev:            1.1081
  Sample StdDev:      1.1081
  Skewness:           0.0001
  Kurtosis:           1.8016
  Avg Dev:            0.9592
  Sum:            64487.8293
  Sum Sq.:       164887.7903

  Mean Err.:          0.0060
  Std Dev Err.:       0.0043
  Skewness Err.:      0.0134
  Kurtosis Err.:      0.0267

  Minimum:            0.0000 [    0]
  Maximum:            3.8335 [33655]
  Quartile:           0.9581 
  Median:             1.9168 
  Quartile:           2.8732
```

which I do not want to see

Could someone please tell me how to set the stats command so that it do not show the stats data on terminal?

Comment: Please edit your Q to show your required output from executing the `stats` command,  or are you saying you don't want **any output**? If that is what you want, then try `stats .... >/dev/null 2>&1`. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Add `nooutput`:

```
stats case.".data.agr" u 4 nooutput
```

You can get help about gnuplot commands with `help command` from the gnuplot command line, in your case: `help stats`.